# PostgreSQL distinct and group on different fields

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, union, greatest-n-per-group

With the following query I can get the list of project members added in the memberships table, union'ed with the the projects owners (who may not have an entry in the memberships table)

```
select sub.user, sub.project, sub.role, sub.order, sub.name from
(SELECT 
    memberships."user",
    memberships.project,
    memberships.role,
    roles."order",
    roles.name
FROM memberships
    JOIN roles ON roles.id = memberships.role
UNION
    SELECT projects.owner AS "user",
        projects.id AS project,
        1 AS role,
        0 AS "order",
        'admin'::text AS name
    FROM projects
) as sub
```

The above query yields the following result set.

```
8   2   1   0   "admin"
8   1   3   2   "contributor"       (added through memberships table)
6   1   1   0   "admin"
8   4   1   0   "admin"
8   1   1   0   "admin"             (duplicate because user #8 is the owner of project #1)
```

Now I want to remove the duplicate entries by taking the contents of the row that has least `order`. using `distinct on (sub.order)` does not include all rows

```
select distinct on (sub.order) * from
-- the same subquery
order by sub.order
```

The above yields

```
8   2   1   0   "admin"
8   1   3   2   "contributor"
```

Using `group by sub.user, sub.project` and aggregating `min(sub.order)` works but the other two fields like `role` and `name` is left out

```
select sub.user, sub.project, min(sub.order) from
-- the same subquery
group by sub.user, sub.project
```

I want the `role`, `name` and `order` of the row that has the minimum `order` when grouped with `user, project` pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the role, name and order of the row that has the minimum order when grouped with user, project pair

The `distinct on` must enumerate the "grouping" columns - then the `order by` clause must contain the same columns, followed by the column(s) to use to break the ties.

You probably want:

```
select distinct on (t.user, t.project) * 
from ( 
    -- the same subquery -- 
) t
order by t.user, t.project, t.order
```